# Cause of "Unable to start activity , NullPointerException"

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

In my main activity I have two buttons and after clicking on one of the buttons,
It should go to the next activity but it is giving following errors in logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION:main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.suven/com.android.suven.Create_Memo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
```

Comment: Have you declared that particular activity in your manifest?

Comment: [Why NullPointerException ?](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/why-nullpointerexception-occures-in.html)

Comment: all you need to do is register the or declare your activity in the manifest file.

Comment: yes. i have declared my 2nd activity in manifest file. but still it is giving me an error.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".BackupRestoreActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Create_memo" android:label="@string/app_name" > 
        <intent-filter>
 <action android:name="com.android.suven.Create_memo" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
   </activity>

Answer (score 1):

Register that another activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivityName"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you get this because you haven't declared your other activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Make sure you declare all activities.

If this does not do the trick, you could try posting some more information, like code snippets of your Manifest file, the code which switches between activities, the line that crashes, etc.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".BackupRestoreActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Create_memo" android:label="@string/app_name" > 
        <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.suven.Create_memo" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
   </activity>

Answer (score 1):

First check that have u added in AndroidManifest.xml ?

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
```